# Multi-table inheritance and two many to many via through model not working in admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin, django-4.1

I'm trying to create navigation menu from the django admin as per user's requirement.
The Model look like this:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Title of the item')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(MenuItem):
    """
    To display non-hierarchical pages such as about us, or some page in menu
    """
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='End of url')
    content = HTMLField(help_text='Contents of the page')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class Category(MenuItem):
    """
    For hierarchical display eg. in navigation menu use Category and Articles.
    """
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='End of url')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
```

Page and Category can be different types of menu items, so, I used inheritance. Now I want to bind the MenuItem to a Menu, hence I added two more models below.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='Name of the menu.')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem, through='MenuLevel', through_fields=['menu', 'menu_item'])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class MenuLevel(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    level = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent', null=True, blank=True)
```

I need the parent key to menu item to traverse through the menu items from parent to children and level to sort the menu in order.

On the admin I have two simple classes:

```
class MenuLevelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MenuLevel

@admin.register(Menu)
class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MenuLevelInline]
```

Here is the problem:
If I try to save two categories, one as a parent to another, things work fine. However, if I have a category as a parent and Page as a child I get IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error.

When I look in the database, the menu_item table does contain all the keys for both Categories and pages table.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everything just worked once I switched to MySQL. It was not working on Sqlite. I don't know why it doesn't work with sqlite maybe it is a bug. But changing the database solved my problem.